# Is there a faster way to query from NDB using list?

Tags: python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have a list that I I need to query the corresponding information from.
I can do:

```py
for i in list:
  database.query(infomation==i).fetch()
```

but this is so slow, because for every element in the list, it have to go to data base and then back, repeat, instead of querying everything at once. Is there a way to speed this process up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the ndb async operations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async) to speed up your code. Basically you would launch all your queries pretty much in parallel, then process the results as they come in, which would result in potentially much faster overall execution, especially if your list is long. Something along these lines:

```
futures = []
for i in list:
     futures.append(
         database.query(infomation==i).fetch_async())
for future in futures:
    results = future.get_result()
    # do something with your results
```

There are more advanced ways of using the async operations described in the mentioned doc which you may find interesting, depending on the structure of your actual code.